# TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

**Given:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns="   index    who     msg    num ".split(),
    data= [
            [       1,  "U1", "ALRM",     2, ],
            [       2,  "U1", "ALRM",     5, ],
            [       3,  "U3", "ALRM",     6, ],
            [       4,  "U3", "ALRM",     2, ],
            [       5,  "U3", "INFO",     3, ],]).set_index("index", drop=True)

gp = df.groupby('who')
```

**The following code will generate the exception as shown in title:**

```
gp.agg(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))

>>>
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\numeric.py in to_numeric(arg, errors, downcast)
    139         values = np.array([arg], dtype="O")
    140     elif getattr(arg, "ndim", 1) > 1:
--> 141         raise TypeError("arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series")
    142     else:
    143         values = arg

TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series
```

**QUESTION:**
the question is **NOT** about "how to fix it", the following will fix it:

```
gp.agg(lambda x: list(pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')) )
or
gp.agg(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce').sum() )
or any operation that reduces "x" in lambda into a NONE-sr or NONE-df
```

The question **IS** about the inner workings of how `.agg()` is carried out, because, I do not see how the exception can be generated by the logic in the exception's text:

```
    140     elif getattr(arg, "ndim", 1) > 1: # <=========== This logic here
    141         raise TypeError("arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series")
```

Specifically, under no circumstance, `x` in `lambda` expression, being `to_numeric()`-ed upon has multi dimensions. I reached at the conclusion in the previous sentence by running this:

```
gp.agg(lambda x: print('\n-----a new x------\n', x, sep=''))

>>>

-----a new x------
1    ALRM
2    ALRM
Name: msg, dtype: object

-----a new x------
3    ALRM
4    ALRM
5    INFO
Name: msg, dtype: object

-----a new x------
1    2
2    5
Name: num, dtype: int64

-----a new x------
3    6
4    2
5    3
Name: num, dtype: int64
```

which, shows that, only one 1-D `series` at a time is fed into the `to_numeric()`. I am more or less expecting the Exception to be something like `can't assign a series back into a cell of a df`

Comment: The exception I get is quite a bit longer than what you have, and shows `ValueError: no results`, followed by `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`, followed by a longer stracktrace culminiated in your error message. The original exception also originates from `pandas/core/base.py in _aggregate_multiple_funcs(self, arg, _axis)`, which is much closer to `.agg` usage than the error message you show here.

Comment: The logic of your error message is, of course, that the whole "msg" column isn't numeric, so the conversion fails for that entire column/series. The `errors="coerce"` (or `errors="ignore"`) will not help there.

Comment: Moreover, your conversion function isn't an aggregate function, so I'm not sure what your goal is.

Comment: @9769953 `errors="coerce"` will turn none-numerics to be np.nan, I don't think that's the problem here. I my post, "the follow will fix it", you can see, `to_numeric` working quite well. The example is highly condensed simple example, there is no goal to make this simle example work. The goal is trying to understand how exactly .agg() work, or anything I am missing here.

Comment: But you expect an exception, correct? Just with a different error message?

Comment: @9769953 yes, the exception is expected. more about why such exception. It may be simple to find out what's wrong in a simple example, but in real world situation, that exception message is very misleading, and to me, just wrong, arg IS already 1-d series. In real world situation, that error would make me doubt so many other things, was my lambda wrong, was the syntax for the func in lamba wrong, was my groupby wrong, was my agg setup wrong?

Comment: Well, the doubt about the lambda being wrong is correct, in that it doesn't reduce the input. But anyway, this gets into the wrong details.

Comment: What you possibly want, is some kind of extra check (thus, more lines of code) in Pandas that will provide a clearer error message. You could create an issue with this example on the Pandas github. Perhaps the developers are willing to try and implement it, but I guess it has low priority.

Comment: As to why this happens, and how exactly one arrives at this error: you're probably best off grabbing a debugger (Python pdb should work fine) and use that to trace what's exactly going on in your example case. Apart from a few calls to C functions, you should be able to follow the logic flow in the code quite precisely.